# composer install - define directory

Tags: composer-php, sh

I'm running a shell script to execute `composer install` command.

my `composer.json` file is in `/var/www/html`

Is there a way I can tell composer not to run under the current directory and to run the composer.json in /var/www/html ?

This is what i've done - but it feels wrong:

```
cd /var/www/html && composer install
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change directory to `/var/www/html` and then do the `composer install` like so:

```
cd /var/www/html && composer install
```

**UPDATE**

Actually a better way to do it would be using `--working-dir` or `-d` option.

```
composer install -d=/var/www/html
```

or

```
composer install --working-dir=/var/www/html
```

Comment: That is actually what I did, it just looked wrong to me.. felt like composer probably have something generic for that